# `conky` without `lua`: can a bar be reverted?

Tags: conky

With [`lua`](https://www.lua.org/) you definitely [can](https://github.com/fisadev/conky-draw).

What about without [`lua`](https://www.lua.org/)? Can [`conky`](https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky) draw a bar not left-to-right like this for 10%:
█░░░░░░░░░
but right-to-left like this?:
░░░░░░░░░█

E.g. the [`Rainmeter`](https://www.rainmeter.net/) for [`Windows`](https://nowindows.su/) does reverting with [`Flip=1`](https://forum.rainmeter.net/viewtopic.php?t=11444#p65399).

Specifically, I prefer `fs_free` to `fs_used`, and would like the `fs_bar` to be coherent, displaying **used** dimly on the left-hand side and highlighting **free** on the right-hand side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a proper flip, but you can try to "emulate" it

[image: screenshot]

```
# cat ~/.conkyrc
total_run_times 0
alignment top_middle
border_width 0
border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0
default_color white
own_window_colour black
draw_borders no
draw_outline no
draw_shades no
use_xft yes
minimum_size  500 50
maximum_width 500
extra_newline no
double_buffer yes
own_window yes
own_window_class Conky
own_window_type desktop
default_bar_size 0 51
default_graph_size 0 24
update_interval 1.0

TEXT
${color green}other content
${color  blue}${voffset   0}${execibar 3600 echo 61.8%}
${color  blue}${voffset -52}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color green}${voffset -25}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}vanilla conky bar given 61.8%
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  12}${hr 50}
${color  blue}${voffset -44}${execibar 3600 echo 61.8%}
${color  blue}${voffset -52}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color green}${voffset -25}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}custom color for 38.2% on the right
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  12}${hr 50}
${color  blue}${voffset -44}${execibar 3600 echo 61.8%}
${color black}${voffset -81}${hr 1}
${color black}${voffset  27}${hr 1}
${color  blue}${voffset -48}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color green}${voffset -25}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}no bar border
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  12}${hr 50}
${color black}${voffset -44}${execibar 3600 echo 61.8%}
${color green}${voffset -81}${hr 1}
${color green}${voffset  27}${hr 1}
${color  blue}${voffset -48}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -23}${alignc}${offset -1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color  blue}${voffset -24}${alignc}${offset  1}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color green}${voffset -25}${alignc}${offset  0}${font DejaVu Sans:size=12}conky-style bar right-to-left
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
${color green}${voffset  15}other content
```

Here, we put a rectangle `${hr 50}` below a bar `default_bar_size 0 51` `${execibar 3600 echo 61.8%}` on z-axis.
We put them in position with `${voffset -...}`.
Things moved upwards will cover whatever is there.

This approach makes right-hand-side look highlighted, but doesn't actually flip the bar. For built-in `fs_bar` and `fs_bar_free` this works fine. For others like `battery_bar` it doesn't.
For when you get your values via `execbar` and friends, you need to feed percentage subtracted from 100, like these:

```
$(( 100 - 62 ))  # integers, not floats

echo '100 - 61.8' | bc
bc -e "100 - $(echo 61.8)" -e quit

echo 61.8 | awk '{print 100 - $1}'
awk 'BEGIN { while ("echo 61.8" | getline var) print 100 - var }'

echo 61.8 | perl -nE 'say 100 - $_'
perl -E 'say 100 - `echo 61.8`'
```

Horizontal bar borders can be:

- preserved (2nd bar)
- masked (3rd bar)
- made look right-to-left (4th bar)

Borders in 3rd and 4th bars are manipulated with `${hr 1}` and `${voffset -...}`

For text to be clearly visible on both colors, we outline it via putting additional 8 same text strings, placing them 1 pixel off in each of 4 straight and 4 diagonal directions.

`xcolor(1)` utility (circle showing "ent" inside) can be used as an aid to zoom into details.

There are undesired leftovers on the very right of bars, which I don't know how to get rid of. Please share.

When you `${voffset -...}`, the conky window doesn't shrink vertically and you are left with overly long window. Just put it at the bottom of the screen or cover with another conky window or panel or something. Please share if there is a correct solution.